# MySQL "auto"-encrypt per session

Tags: mysql, encryption

Is there a way to tell the server to en|de-crypt columns per session?

*to not use ENCRYPT on queries*

What im thinking of is

- connect to mysql server and provide secret (encryption key)
- server has config to en|edcrypt defined columns
- server receives query and auto-decrypt columns by config using the secret given on connection

Im just curious if something like this exists.

Comment: @Shadow this is not a duplicate of the post you added. Im asking if a feature exists. And if so what its called.

Comment: What you are looking for is called encryption at rest. Hence the duplicate.